# Nullpointer in Spring Boot 2 Actuator Starter w. TomcatMetrics

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I have recently upgraded our system from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2.1.3 and added the `spring-boot-starter-actuator`. Apparently, something is misconfigured, as there is a `NullPointerException` in `TomcatMetrics::registerMetricsEventually`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.tomcat.TomcatMetrics.lambda$registerMetricsEventually$aa4da135$1(TomcatMetrics.java:260)
    at java.management/javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport.sendNotification(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:238)
    at java.management/javax.management.MBeanServerDelegate.sendNotification(MBeanServerDelegate.java:211)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.sendNotification(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1473)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1867)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:955)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:890)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:320)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.registerComponent(Registry.java:639)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.register(AbstractProtocol.java:1059)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:823)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

The null pointer occurs here:

```
return objectName.getDomain().equals(getJmxDomain()) && objectName.getKeyProperty(key).equals(value);
```

because `objectName.getKeyProperty("j2eeType")` returns null.

Is this an indication of something being obviously misconfigured?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide

Comment: Can you post your gradle/maven dependencies?  For sure check that the version of micrometer you are pulling in works with boot 2.1.x.

Comment: I have same issue, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I am running with dependencies shown below for spring boot 2.1.8 and even added runtime scope to the pom for micrometer but it did not help. Actuator is looking for the value of the same key ("j2eeType") and not handling it gracefully.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
     <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
     <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.6</version>
     <scope>runtime</scope>
 </dependency>
```